# Windows 10 Xbox streaming - Keyboard and mouse?

Tags: windows-10-preview, keymap, xbox-one

I have been testing Xbox game streaming in Windows 10. When streaming a game, the Xbox app only supports controllers(gamepads). Would it be possible to map both the mouse and keyboard to the controller to essentially trick the Xbox program into thinking a controller is being used when it would be keyboard & mouse?

Comment: Write software to test it out and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could if you wanted to cheat at FPS / TPS titles using xpadder or similar to emulate an Xbox One controller from KB+M. I know there are programs to emulate mouse as analog for emulating console FPS like the Metroid Prime trilogy, Goldeneye, Perfect Dark, etc.

Note that this IS cheating, because mouse+keyboard DEMOLISH controllers (PC Master Race!) in Games Where You Shoot Guns (tm) AND you even keep the auto-aim that makes controllers almost-sort-of-usable. If you do pull off an emulated controller to use your KB+M in Master Chief Collection / Halo 5 and Microsoft finds out, you might get a Live suspension.

ED: Upvoted the question, because I want to go on a rampage through Halo MCC with mouse aiming and put it on YouTube now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it out myself yet, but theoretically you might be able to use a program like xpadder to map the keyboard to the controller buttons. It works for a lot of emulators and games that don't natively support an xbox controller.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin for [FreePIE](http://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/) with a dependency on [SCPSever](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpServer) that allows you to emulate output as an Xbox controller. Technically you could write a script that would allow you to use a keyboard and mouse (or another joystick). The plugin hasn't really been very well tested, and I wasn't quite sure what I was doing too much when writing the code, but it seemed to work for basic examples.

https://github.com/dschu012/XOutputPlugin

Feel free to contribute to it if you find any issues.